# SQL error in Creating Table: Missing Parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create 3 associated tables

```
/*create customer_dml ---this works fine*/

DROP TABLE Customer_DML;
CREATE TABLE Customer_DML
(
 customerId CHAR(10) CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY, 
 ssn CHAR(9) CONSTRAINT customer_uq_ssn UNIQUE,
 firstName VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT customer_nn_fname NOT NULL,
 lastName VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT customer_nn_lname NOT NULL,
 phoneNumber CHAR(10),
 address VARCHAR (100)
);

/*create account_dml- this gets missing right parenthesis error*/

DROP TABLE Account_DML;

CREATE TABLE Account_DML
(
  AccountNumber CHAR(10) CONSTRAINT account_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  CustomerId CHAR(10) 
  CONSTRAINT account_nn_customerId NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT account_fk_customerid REFERENCES Customer_DML(customerId)
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  Type CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT account_ck_type CHECK (Type IN ('C','S')),
  balance NUMBER(8,2) CONSTRAINT account_nn_balance NOT NULL,
  AcctOpenDate DATE CONSTRAINT account_nn_acctopendate NOT NULL,
);

/*create CreditCard_dml --this gets right parenthesis error*/

 CREATE TABLE CreditCard 
(
  cardNumber CHAR (16) CONSTRAINT creditCard_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  customerId CHAR (10) CONSTRAINT creditCard_fk_customerId 
    REFERENCES Customer_DML (customerId)
    ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  limit NUMBER(8,2) creditCard_nn_limit NOT NULL, 
  expirationDate DATE CONSTRAINT creditCard_nn_expirationDate NOT NULL
);
```

What am I doing wrong to cause the following error message?

> Error report - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Is there a way to get a more specific error code so that I can try and figure out where I went wrong?

Comment: You have an extra comma after `Customer_DML(customerId)`?

Comment: i deleted that from the Create Account table constraint line and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not an Oracle user, but I think `CONSTRAINT account_fk_customerid REFERENCES Customer_DML(customerId),
  ON DELETE CASCADE` should not have a comma in the middle.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks, i tried that and i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug DDL is to remove one line at a time until it works, then start adding those lines back in, one at a time, until you can isolate the exact line or lines that are problematic.

In your DDL, you have multiple syntax problems, all related to the `constraint` syntax.

When you declare a constraint, you give it a name, then the column(s) the constraint belongs to. You omitted that second part.

`CONSTRAINT account_nn_customerId NOT NULL` should be `CONSTRAINT account_nn_customerId CustomerID NOT NULL`

`CONSTRAINT account_fk_customerid REFERENCES Customer_DML(customerId) ON DELETE CASCADE,` should be `CONSTRAINT account_fk_customerid foreign key (CustomerId) REFERENCES Customer_DML(customerId) ON DELETE CASCADE,`

Those two example corrections should get you going to fix the other syntax errors.